Sorting a permutation by sorting half of the elements at a time
The problem: suppose we have an array $p[1..n]$ (where $n$ is a multiple of 4) which initially contains some permutation of the numbers $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$.  The only way we are allowed to modify this array is with the following operation: we can choose $n/2$ indices $1 \le i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_{n/2} \le n$ and sort the elements $p[i_1], \ldots, p[i_{n/2}]$ in-place.  In other words, move the smallest of these values to index $i_1$ of the array, the second smallest value to index $i_2$ and so on.  What's the minimum number of these operations that we need to sort the array?
Summary of what I found out so far:

Any permutation can be sorted in at most three operations.
A permutation with no fixed points can not be sorted in two operations; it requires three [ETA: unless you can divide the cycles into two groups with $n/2$ elements in each group].
Of the permutations with 1 fixed point, some can be sorted in two operations and some can't.
Of the permutations with $\ge 2$ fixed points, I haven't been able to find any that requires three operations (it has always been possible to sort them in two operations), but I also haven't been able to prove that no such permutations exist.  This is the part I'm stuck on; if anyone here has any ideas towards solving this, I would be very interested to hear them.

Below are more details of my thinking so far:
To see that three operations are always enough: In the first operation, we choose indices $1, 2, \ldots, n/4$, as well as those indices from the range $n/4 + 1, \ldots, n$ which contain the smallest elements from that part of the array.  This will ensure that in the first operation, the values $1, 2, \ldots, n/4$ arrive at their correct position on indices $1, 2, \ldots, n/4$.  In the second operation we deal similarly with indices $n/4 + 1, \ldots, n/2$.  In the third operation we sort the rest of the array (indices $n/2 + 1, \ldots, n$).
When considering whether $\le 2$ operations are enough:  We can think of $p$ as a permutation and split it into cycles.  Each cycle of length 1 represents a fixed point --- a value that is already in the "correct" position (i.e. where it will also be when $p$ is fully sorted).  All elements on cycles of length $> 1$ are in "wrong" positions (i.e. not where they will be when $p$ is sorted).
If, when choosing indices for our sorting operation, we always choose them so that a cycle is either included in its entirety or not at all, it is easy to see that all the elements of the chosen cycles will reach their correct positions.  Thus, if we can divide the cycles into two groups of $n/2$ elements, we can sort the array with two operations instead of three.  And of course if $n/2$ or fewer elements were in the wrong positions to begin with, only one operation is enough.
This leaves us with the case where the cycles can not be divided into two groups with $n/2$ elements in each group.  This means that the first operation will have to include at least one cycle only partially (along with perhaps some cycles being included in their entirety).  Suppose that we have a cycle $(c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_k)$, of which we only include $c_a, c_{a+1}, \ldots, c_b$ as indices for our sorting operation.  On these indices of $p$ there are the values $c_{a+1},  c_{a+2}, \ldots, c_{b+1}$.  Thus our sorting operation includes the index $c_a$, but not the value $c_a$ (because this value is currently stored in $p[c_{a-1}]$, and the index $c_{a-1}$ is not included in our operation); thus the index $c_a$ will still not contain the correct value after our sorting operation.
Similarly, if our sorting operation includes several such groups of contiguous indices from one or more cycles, the first index of each group is sure to contain the wrong value after the operation.  If there were $g$ such groups in our operation, then at most $n/2 - g$ of the elements covered by the operation will be in their correct positions after the operation.
Thus, if initially all $n$ elements were in wrong positions, the only way to sort them with two operations would be if each brings $n/2$ elements to correct positions; but we've just seen that, since the cycles can't be split into two groups of $n/2$ elements, the first sorting operation will move strictly less than $n/2$ elements to correct positions; therefore such an array can't be sorted in two operations.
If initially $n-1$ elements were in wrong positions (i.e. if the permutation $p$ had one fixed point), we can sort them in two operations if the first one puts at least $n/2 - 1$ elements in correct positions, which means it may contain at most $g = 1$ group of contiguous indices from a cycles that is not included in its entirety (in addition to that it may contain zero or more cycles that get included in their entirety).  It would not be hard to imagine an algorithm to test all these possibilities; it would be polynomial-time in $n$.
Now, of course this would be easy to generalize; if $p$ has $g$ fixed points, our first operation may contain up to $g$ groups of contiguous indices (so that it has any chance of putting at least $n/2 - g$ elements in correct positions), and we could test them all in time that would be polynomial in $n$, but unfortunately exponential in $g$.
But, as I mentioned earlier in this post, despite much trying, I haven't been able to find any example of a permutation $p$ with $\ge 2$ fixed points which could not be sorted with two operations.  What is more, I haven't even found any permutation where the first operation would have to include more than two groups of contiguous indices (in addition perhaps to some cycles included in their entirety) --- in fact in the vast majority of cases one group is enough (though there are some permutations that require two groups).  So we could avoid exponential time complexity if we could prove that two groups are always enough.  Or, even if it turns out that two groups are not always enough, it might still be the case that any permutation with $\ge 2$ fixed points can be sorted in two operations, and it would be interesting if this could be proven (even if non-constructively).
Update: I have now found some permutations with $\ge 2$ fixed points which do require three operations to get sorted.  For 2 fixed points, the shortest such permutation had 18 elements; for one fixed point, the shortest had 8 elements.  From those two examples I came up with the following generalization: if you want an example with $f$ fixed points, take $n = 2(f + 1)^2$ and let $p = [n - 3f, ..., n-f, 1, ..., n - 3f - 1, n  - f + 1, ..., n]$.  The last $f$ elements of $p$ are fixed points, the rest of $p$ forms one big cycle.  For $f = 1, 2, 3$, I verified with a computer that these cases do indeed require three operations (i.e. two operations are not enough).  Now this opens up two new questions:

Can we prove that the array $p$ as constructed here really requires three operations for every $f$?

And is (as I suspect) $n = 2(f + 1)^2$ the smallest $n$ for which there exists a permutation with $f$ fixed points that requires three operations to get sorted?



"A permutation with no fixed points can not be sorted in two operations; it requires three" - I think that your argument shows that some can (for example, if we have two cycles with length $n / 2$ each).

Hm yes, you're right - I should have written: it requires three, unless you can divide the cycles into two groups with $n/2$ elements in each group.
